# Passing a variable to an external route

Tags: node.js, express

I have a Node js and Express web app.

My app.js looks like

```
var pages_route = require('./route/pages');

/*
---------------------
------ ROUTE --------
---------------------
*/

app.get('/', pages_route.index);//home
```

My route/pages.js looks like

```
exports.index = function(req, res){

  res.render( 'home.ejs');

};
```

I'm trying to pass the view name for every route from the app.js file like the follow:

```
app.get('/', pages_route.index), template = 'home';
```

In route/pages.js

```
 exports.index = function(req, res){

      res.render( template + '.ejs');

    };
```

This solution works fine for a single route, but when I create more than one like

```
app.get('/', pages_route.index), template = 'home';
app.get('/custompage', pages_route.custom), template = 'skeleton';
```

The app will take the last view name passed for all the routes, in this case the view "skeleton" will be printed for all my routes.

I don't want to create a different instance for every route like template1, template2, template3 etc.. I just want to find a solution similar to my example.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Express doesn't give you just `req` and `res` like native node.  It also gives you `next`

Next allows you build middleware, functions that occur as part of handling the request, but don't necessarily end the request.

Here's an example for your use case:

```
// middleware
function setTemplate (template) {
  return function applyTemplate (req, res, next) {
    req.template = template;
    next();
  };
}

// route
app.get('/', setTemplate('home'), pages_route.index);

// handler
exports.index = function (req, res) {
  res.render(req.template + '.ejs');
};
```